# Trying to "stich back" tokenized responses into a Panda df using a function - getting "self._engine.get_loc(casted key)"error message

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to join tokenized responses into a dataframe - keep getting self.engine.get_loc(casted key) error message. Can anyone help?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYU8q.png)

Expecting to be able to de-tokenize - then add to my df

Comment: Could you post an example of that tokenized_responses looks like?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.